# Converting Pig output into JSON Format

Tags: arrays, json, hadoop, apache-pig

I have the following output in Pig stored in a variable:

```
("Keyword",
{
(data1, data2, data3, data4),
(data1, data2, data3, data4)
}
)
```

Expecting output in JSON format:

```
{
    "keyword": [
        {
            "val_1": "data1",
            "val_2": "data2",
            "val_3": "data3",
            "val_4": "data4"
        },
        {
            "val_1": "data1",
            "val_2": "data2",
            "val_3": "data3",
            "val_4": "data4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have defined a schema, all you got to do is -

```
store yourRelation into 'file_location_in_hdfs' using JsonStorage();
```

This will use the schema, variable names as the json tags.

Comment: Yes you would need to specify schema to be able to use this storage, try loading a sample data with schema, do a group all on it and store using JSONStorage, the data will have output format similar to yours.